# How to update value of nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, recursion

This is my actual array :

```
let mainArray= [
    {
        value: '/AG_TURF-123',
        label: 'Ag & Turf',
        checked: false,
        id:123,
        children: [
            {
                value: '/AG_TURF-123/TRACTOR-456',
                label: 'Tractors',
                checked: false,
                id:456,
                children: [
                    {
                        value: '/AG_TURF-123/TRACTOR-456/Large-7-8-9-series',
                        label: 'Large (7, 8, 9) Series',
                        checked: false,
                        id:789,
                        children: [{
                            value: '/AG_TURF-123/TRACTOR-456/Large-7-8-9-series/7-family-tractor',
                            label: '7 Family Tractor',
                            checked: false,
                            id:101112
                        },{
                            value: '/AG_TURF-123/TRACTOR-456/Large-7-8-9-series/8-family-tractor',
                            label: '8 Family Tractor',
                            checked: false,
                            id:131415
                        },{
                            value: '/AG_TURF-123/TRACTOR-456/Large-7-8-9-series/9-family-tractor',
                            label: '9 Family Tractor',
                            checked: false,
                            id:161718
                        }],
                    },
                    {
                        value: '/app/Http/routes.js',
                        label: 'routes.js',
                        checked: false,
                        id:181920
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                value: '/app/Providers',
                label: 'Providers',
                checked: false,
                id:212223,
                children: [{
                    value: '/app/Http/Providers/EventServiceProvider.js',
                    label: 'EventServiceProvider.js',
                    checked: false,
                    id:242526
                }],
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        value: '/config',
        label: 'config',
        checked: false,
        id:272829,
        children: [
            {
                value: '/config/app.js',
                label: 'app.js',
                checked: false,
                id:303132
            },
            {
                value: '/config/database.js',
                label: 'database.js',
                checked: false,
                id:333435
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        value: '/public',
        label: 'public',
        checked: false,
        id:353637,
        children: [
            {
                value: '/public/assets/',
                label: 'assets',
                checked: false,
                id:383940,
                children: [{
                    value: '/public/assets/style.css',
                    label: 'style.css',checked: false,
                    id:404142
                }],
            },
            {
                value: '/public/index.html',
                label: 'index.html',
                checked: false,
                id: 434445
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        value: '/.env',
        label: '.env',
        checked: false,
        id: 464748
    },
    {
        value: '/.gitignore',
        label: '.gitignore',
        checked: false,
        id: 495051
    },
    {
        value: '/README.md',
        label: 'README.md',
        checked: false,
        id: 525354
    },
];
```

This is my list of value :

`const ids=[525354,123,131415];`

I want to set `checked` to `true` if id matched.
My main array may go to 6 to 7 step deep.

What I've done till yet :

```
setCheckedFlagToItems(checkList, items) {
        return items.map((item) => {
            const node = item;
            if (checkList.indexOf(node.id) !== -1) {
                node.checked = true;
            }
            if ((node.children) && (Array.isArray(node.children) && node.children.length > 0)) {
                this.setCheckedFlagToItems(checkList, node.children);
            }
            return node;
        }, this);
    }
```

But it not working as usual.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use an iterative and recursice approach with a named function as callback for [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

```js
let mainArray = [
{
    value: '/AG_TURF-123', 
    label: 'Ag & Turf', 
    checked: false, 
    id: 123, 
    children: [
        { 
            value: '/AG_TURF-123/TRACTOR-456', 
            label: 'Tractors', 
            checked: false, 
            id: 456, 
            children: [
                { 
                    value: '/AG_TURF-123/TRACTOR-456/Large-7-8-9-series', 
                    label: 'Large (7, 8, 9) Series', 
                    checked: false, 
                    id: 789, 
                    children: [
                        { 
                            value: '/AG_TURF-123/TRACTOR-456/Large-7-8-9-series/7-family-tractor', 
                            label: '7 Family Tractor', 
                            checked: false, 
                            id: 101112 
                        }, 
                        { 
                            value: '/AG_TURF-123/TRACTOR-456/Large-7-8-9-series/8-family-tractor', 
                            label: '8 Family Tractor', 
                            checked: false, 
                            id: 131415 
                        }, 
                        { 
                            value: '/AG_TURF-123/TRACTOR-456/Large-7-8-9-series/9-family-tractor', 
                            label: '9 Family Tractor', 
                            checked: false, 
                            id: 161718 
                        }
                    ] 
                }, 
                {
                    value: '/app/Http/routes.js', 
                    label: 'routes.js', 
                    checked: false, 
                    id: 181920 
                }
            ]
        }, 
        { 
            value: '/app/Providers', 
            label: 'Providers', 
            checked: false, 
            id: 212223, 
            children: [
                { 
                    value: '/app/Http/Providers/EventServiceProvider.js', 
                    label: 'EventServiceProvider.js', 
                    checked: false, 
                    id: 242526 
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}, 
{
    value: '/config', 
    label: 'config', 
    checked: false, 
    id: 272829, 
    children: [
        {
            value: '/config/app.js', 
            label: 'app.js', 
            checked: false, 
            id: 303132
        },
        {
            value: '/config/database.js', 
            label: 'database.js', 
            checked: false, 
            id: 333435 
        }
    ]
}, 
{
    value: '/public', 
    label: 'public', 
    checked: false, 
    id: 353637, 
    children: [
        {
            value: '/public/assets/', 
            label: 'assets', 
            checked: false, 
            id: 383940, 
            children: [
                {
                    value: '/public/assets/style.css', 
                    label: 'style.css', 
                    checked: false, 
                    id: 404142
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            value: '/public/index.html', 
            label: 'index.html', 
            checked: false, 
            id: 434445 
        }
    ] 
}, 
{ 
    value: '/.env', 
    label: '.env', 
    checked: false, 
    id: 464748 
}, 
{ 
    value: '/.gitignore', 
    label: '.gitignore', 
    checked: false, 
    id: 495051 
}, 
{ 
    value: '/README.md', 
    label: 'README.md', 
    checked: false, 
    id: 525354 
}
],
    ids = [525354, 123, 131415];

mainArray
    .forEach(
        function iter(a) {
            if (ids.includes(a.id)) {
                a.checked = true;
            }
            Array.isArray(a.children) && a.children.forEach(iter);
        }
    );

console.log(mainArray);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @Kris Hollenbeck, your edit does not really check the array if it is one or not for the recursive iteration, which is necessary.

Comment: Hmm.. Maybe I looked at it wrong. It was throwing an error in my IDE. The old code was `Array.isArray( (a.children) && a.children.forEach(callback);`  .. I was getting `)` expected. So a missing parenthesis.

Comment: Maybe it should have been `Array.isArray( a.children) && a.children.forEach(iter);` ?

Comment: ^^ it looks like the original ... and intended.

Comment: yeah your right. It was a tslint error I saw I guess. Sorry about that. http://imgur.com/a/hRMAI

Answer (score 4):

If your `id`s are "unique" (there's only one unique object for each `id` property), you could also split this action in to two steps:

1. Make a new data structure that flattens all items in to one object of `id: item`
2. Loop through the `ids` to retrieve the items from this object.

If you find yourself looking up many objects by `id`, it might be easier to create this interim representation.

The creation of the map uses recursion similar to the other answer: whenever an `item` contains a `children` array, it adds those to the map object before it returns.

```js
const mainArray = [{ value: '/AG_TURF-123', label: 'Ag & Turf', checked: false, id: 123, children: [{ value: '/AG_TURF-123/TRACTOR-456', label: 'Tractors', checked: false, id: 456, children: [{ value: '/AG_TURF-123/TRACTOR-456/Large-7-8-9-series', label: 'Large (7, 8, 9) Series', checked: false, id: 789, children: [{ value: '/AG_TURF-123/TRACTOR-456/Large-7-8-9-series/7-family-tractor', label: '7 Family Tractor', checked: false, id: 101112 }, { value: '/AG_TURF-123/TRACTOR-456/Large-7-8-9-series/8-family-tractor', label: '8 Family Tractor', checked: false, id: 131415 }, { value: '/AG_TURF-123/TRACTOR-456/Large-7-8-9-series/9-family-tractor', label: '9 Family Tractor', checked: false, id: 161718 }] }, { value: '/app/Http/routes.js', label: 'routes.js', checked: false, id: 181920 }] }, { value: '/app/Providers', label: 'Providers', checked: false, id: 212223, children: [{ value: '/app/Http/Providers/EventServiceProvider.js', label: 'EventServiceProvider.js', checked: false, id: 242526 }] }] }, { value: '/config', label: 'config', checked: false, id: 272829, children: [{ value: '/config/app.js', label: 'app.js', checked: false, id: 303132 }, { value: '/config/database.js', label: 'database.js', checked: false, id: 333435 }] }, { value: '/public', label: 'public', checked: false, id: 353637, children: [{ value: '/public/assets/', label: 'assets', checked: false, id: 383940, children: [{ value: '/public/assets/style.css', label: 'style.css', checked: false, id: 404142 }] }, { value: '/public/index.html', label: 'index.html', checked: false, id: 434445 }] }, { value: '/.env', label: '.env', checked: false, id: 464748 }, { value: '/.gitignore', label: '.gitignore', checked: false, id: 495051 }, { value: '/README.md', label: 'README.md', checked: false, id: 525354 }];

// We reduce the array of nested items in to one object of:
// { id: item }
const idMap = mainArray.reduce(function merge(map, node) {
  map[node.id] = node;
  
  if (Array.isArray(node.children)) {
    node.children.reduce(merge, map);
  }
  
  return map;
}, {});

const ids = [525354, 123, 131415];

// Whenever you need an item, you can get it
// using idMap[id]
const items = ids.map(id => idMap[id]);
items.forEach(item => item.checked = true);

// or: ids.forEach(id => idMap[id].checked = true)
```