# How to create/edit/delete from a nested structure in redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am rendering nested data in a table row by row.  Here's a simple example of the structure:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    children: [
      {
        id: 2,
        children: []
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        children: [
          {
            id: 4,
            children: []
          },
          {
            id: 5,
            children: []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    children: []
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    children: [
      {
        id: 8,
        children: [
          {
            id: 9,
            children: []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

If I want to create a new child under `id: 2`, so that it goes from

```
{
  id: 2,
  children: []
}
```

to

```
{
  id: 2,
  children: [
    {
      id: 10,
      children: []
    }
  ]
}
```

What is the correct way to update the state in this case?  Do I just clone this whole array and find the id that's gonna have a new child and plop it into its children[], and return that new cloned array?  What if its a huge array?

Comment: With such a structure I'd use [immutablejs](https://github.com/immutable-js/immutable-js) for those purposes. The real benefit of it is that it always returns a new structure and has very intuitive api (very similar to what javascript has for objects, arrays etc)

Answer (score 1):

With Redux you have to update the state in an immutable manner. You have basically two options:

1. Use `Object.assign` or the [ES6 spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to generate a new object from the current state object: see [Immutable update patterns (Redux docs)](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns#correct-approach-copying-all-levels-of-nested-data)
2. Use one of the multiple libraries that do this for you, I would suggest [Immer](https://github.com/immerjs/immer) but there are other options like [immutablejs](https://github.com/immutable-js/immutable-js) for example.

I really like Immer because it allows me to write clean and easy to read/mantain reducers. Even you can use mutation methods with it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an iterative and recursice approach with a named function as callback for `Array#forEach`

here
 [How to update value of nested array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43612046/how-to-update-value-of-nested-array-of-objects)